# how to remove special character except "/"?

Tags: javascript, jquery

how to remove special character except "/" from a string? What is the regex should i use?

```
"/[^a-z0-9_\s-]/"
```

Im using this regex. It is not working.

Comment: just add `\/` inside the negated class `[^a-z0-9_\s-\/]`

Answer (score 6):

When using `/` in a `/.../` regex syntax you need to escape it with a backslash. Alternatively you can use the `RegExp` constructor to avoid having to escape the `/` : both `/[^\/]/` and `new RegExp("[^/]")` will match any character but `/`.

To remove any special character but `/`, it depends on what you call a special character but I would use `/[^a-zA-Z0-9\/]/`.
If you don't mind underscores you can use `/[^\w\/]/`.

It matches only one character, so you will probably want to use the `g` global flag : `/[^a-zA-Z0-9\/]/g` or `new RegExp("[^a-zA-Z0-9/]", "g")`

Answer (score 0):

Try this as well

```
input.replace(/\W/g, function(match){ return (match == "/" ? match : "") });
```

```js
function replaceExceptChar( input, specialChar )
{
   return   input.replace(/\W/g, function(match){ return (match == specialChar ? match : "") });
}

console.log( replaceExceptChar("asdasd2323(*(&*/", "/") );
```